# Tomcat WAR - Configure Logback to use app name in path

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j, logback

I have logback deployed in my war file lib folder and I have the following logback.xml in the classes folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <property name="destination" value="${catalina.base:-./temp}/logs/${appName:-myapp}" />

  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${destination}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${destination}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- Keep logs for 7 days -->
      <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>

      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

On line 3 I have some variable substitutions that create the path for my log file.

```
  <property name="destination" value="${catalina.base:-./temp}/logs/${appName:-myapp}" />
```

I want to make it so `${appName}` evaluates to the current name of the war file as deployed.

So if my web apps folder looked like so

```
webapps
 - myapp.war
 - myapp-dev.war
```

The `${destination}` property for myapp.war would evaluate to `.../logs/myapp` and myapp-dev.war would evaluate to `.../logs/myapp-dev`. Is there a JNDI property or something I can access to access the appName ?

I would like to avoid having to manually reconfigure the logger.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of doing this. There is an enhancement request for this for JULI (Tomcat's built-in logging) : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43682

Comment: Here is a blog post about another solution to this problem: https://0x0a14.de/adding-the-context-root-to-a-logback-config-file-path/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT 2013-06**: I have made this `Listener` available as OSS on Maven Central. Check out the [project homepage](http://mo-tomcat-ext.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html#LogbackContextNameListener).

Yes, this is feasible. First of all, you can always rely on `catalina.base` because without it Tomcat won't run. In order to inject the context name as property. Write a context [listener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html) which will put the context name into the JNDI context and remove at shutdown. After you have done that, You can retrieve the value with JNDI directly with logback. There is direct support for that. Write that in the the contextName element and you're done.

I have implemented this on my own already and it works for all of my projects. I can share the entire code on monday if you or someone else is interested.

Edit, here is the code:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.deploy.ContextEnvironment;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

public class LogbackContextNameListener implements LifecycleListener {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(LogbackContextNameListener.class);
    private Context context;

    private String name = "logback/contextName";

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent le) {

        if (le.getLifecycle() instanceof Context)
            context = (Context) le.getLifecycle();
        else
            return;

        if (le.getType().equals(Lifecycle.START_EVENT)) {
            ContextEnvironment ce = new ContextEnvironment();
            ce.setName(getName());
            ce.setOverride(false);
            ce.setType("java.lang.String");
            String value = StringUtils.remove(context.getServletContext()
                    .getContextPath(), '/');
            ce.setValue(value);
            logger.debug(String.format("Adding env entry '%s' with value '%s'",
                    getName(), value));
            context.getNamingResources().addEnvironment(ce);
        }

        if (le.getType().equals(Lifecycle.STOP_EVENT)) {
            logger.debug(String.format("Removing env entry '%s'", getName()));
            context.getNamingResources().removeEnvironment(name);
        }

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Parameter 'name' cannot be empty");

        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

A suitable config looks like this:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 minutes">

    <insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/logback/contextName" as="contextName" />
    <contextName>${contextName}</contextName>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/${CONTEXT_NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/${CONTEXT_NAME}.log.%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-27(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%.-12thread]) %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO"><!-- WARN -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

This works flawlessly in Tomcat 6. I guess, it will run on Tomcat 7 w/o changes.

Comment: While I think the approach works well, it requires me to add tomcat as a dependency. Is there any way of doing it with a ServletContextListener ?

Comment: You don't need a dependency. This does not belong in your app, but in a seperate JAR in tomcat/lib. And no, this cannot be done from the applicaton. The JDNI context is read-only from within the app.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying that. Could you also include the configuration change I need to make to have tomcat use my listener ?Thanks

Comment: This is usual [tomcat configuration for listeners](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Lifecycle_Listeners). So it would be:

    <Context>
      ...
      <Listener className="com.mycompany.mypackage.MyListener" ... >
      ...
    </Context>

Comment: if i add this listener to my `@Configuration` class as a `@Bean` it doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

This builds on Michael-O's answer. Considering that `catalina.base` is always a defined system property when running under Tomcat, we only have to worry about defining `appName`. Logback offers support for [retrieving variables from JNDI](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#insertFromJNDI). If appName is defined in JNDI, your configuration file becomes:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- retrieve appName from JNDI to set the variable appName -->
  <insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/appName" as="appName" />
  <!-- let the context name be the applicaiton name -->
  <contextName>${appName}</contextName>

  <property name="destination" 
            value="${catalina.base:-./temp}/logs/${CONTEXT_NAME:-myapp}" />

  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${destination}.log</file>
    ... remainder of config file omitted for brevity  
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

I'd like to mention that you could also just define appName directly in logback.xml instead of in JNDI. (After all, the logback.xml file ships with your web-app where its name is already established. However, your question explicitly excludes this hypothesis.) Thus, you logback.xml file could be simplified to:

```
<configuration>
  <contextName>the_name_of_your_webapp</contextName>
  <property name="destination" 
            value="${catalina.base:-./temp}/logs/${CONTEXT_NAME:-myapp}" />
   ... the rest omitted for brevity
</configuration?
```

BTW, once you find a satisfactory solution, do not hesitate to share it by posting on logback-user list.

Comment: Ceki, if you like, I can open a JIRA ticket a donate my `Listener` to LogBack. It serves the purpose very well.

Comment: Sure, I am always looking for contributions.

Comment: Ceki, thanks for the answer. I think it would be best to have Michael-O's solution added into tomcat and have it set java:comp/env/appName. I don't know how willing they would be to do something like that though.

Comment: HaxElit, won't happen. This is too specific. LogBack could have this listener bundled though. I think `java:comp/env/logback/contextName` or `appName` is a good and unique name for that.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the ContextSelector for? You may have a look at ContextJNDISelector and here http://logback.qos.ch/manual/contextSelector.html

Answer (score 0):

maxHistory doesn't mean the number of log files. It means the number of months.